# How to allocate memory to Vector<Point> dynamically?

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

How to allocate memory to Vector dynamically ?

`vector<Point> vInPts;` // My Input Vector -  i have dumped some value ( of size 6 )

// Doing Some calculation on the input vector points

`vector<Point> vOutPts;` // How to dynamically allocate memory for this output vector Points

Comment: You can use `vOutPts.reserve()`. This will allocate memory without actually filling values into the vector. Or `vOutPts.resize()`, which will allocate space and fill it with default-initialised elements. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are you do not need to allocate the vector itself dynamically. Internally, the vector will allocate the memory it needs to store its elements dynamically, and will take care of managing this memory. So just declare the vector in automatic storage:

```
 vector<Point> vOutPts;
```

You can allocate a predetermined amount of memory for the vector by calling [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

If you absolutely must allocate the vector dynamically, make sure you know all about memory management, and read up on [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the size you want, then you can allocate and initialise enough elements with:

```
vOutPts.resize(size);
```

or you can create it with that size:

```
vector<Point> vOutPts(size);
```

Otherwise, you can grow the vector one element at a time:

```
vOutPts.push_back(some_point);
```

If you know (roughly) how many elements you want to push, then you could make that a bit more efficient by allocating some memory beforehand, without initialising any elements:

```
vOutPts.reserve(approx_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way

```
vector <Point> *myvect= new vector<Point>()
```

But don't forget to call:

```
delete myvect
```

when you're done using it or else you'll create a leak.

Please notice that allocating the vector itself this way won't be the same as allocating dinamically the vector contents. This dynamic allocation of the vector itself should be done only if for example you intend to create a vector inside a function and return it by reference. Automatic memory management is easier to handle, less error prone and above all safer than dynamically allocating objects... and therefore whenever you don't have to you should avoid this dynamic allocation

Comment: That's one possible interpretation of the question, but very bad advice.

Comment: Because it's very unusual (to the extent that I'd suspect a design flaw) to want to dynamically allocate the `vector` object itself. Its used to manage dynamic memory automatically, and adding an extra layer of manual allocation defeats that purpose.

Comment: well necessity to return a vector by reference for example is not that unusual... especially if you have a vector of objects and not a vector of pointers to objects...You're right It shouldn't be usual as the common practice but sometimes there's no alternative.

Comment: Even if you are stuck with an ancient compiler without move semantics, and some weird logic that prevents copy elision, there are better solutions than dynamic allocation for returning a large object from a function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour This answers one particular interpretation of the question. What would your advice be given this interpretation?

Comment: @Sancho: If the question were interpreted as "how do I dynamically a vector?", my advice would be "you don't want to dynamically allocate a vector". If there were some weird circumstances which suggest that you might want to, then my advice would depend on those circumstances.